# Cron: where is the /etc/cron.d defined? Is it possible to add a new directory?

Tags: linux, cron

In CentOS, where is the /etc/cron.d folder defined? Is it possible to add a new folder that works exactly as it?

Example: I have another folder ( /mnt/software/cron ) full of files with the exact format as the one that is expected in /etc/cron.d.

Is it possible to make crond watch this directory and process those cron files? Or will i have to create symlinks in /etc/cron.d?

Comment: It is hard-coded in the source.   You could `mount --bind` the `/etc/cron.d` folder to `/mnt/software/cron` perhaps?  Or simply symmlink the entire directory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `/etc/cron.d` directory isn't changeable, but you might be able to use anacron to get the behavior you want. Look in `/etc/anacrontab` for details of how the hourly, daily, and weekly jobs are called from their respective `cron.${frequency}` directories. This may not work with your currently cron job syntax, but it's a place to start.